# Unable to compare two Lists of Long for differences in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

This seems like a very basic question but I feel as if I'm unable to solve it myself even after reading a few past questions on here.

I have two lists of type long for which I can add data to fine. The problem is that I can't compare them in a third list. I've tried using `.Except()` but that doesn't seem to be a property (as shown by intellisense on VS) for when I try and compare. I've also tried using `IEnumerable` (not 100% sure on what that does so I have some reading on that tomorrow) but that doesn't seem to work either.

I pretty much have the following at the moment:

```
Dim a As New List(Of Long)
Dim b As New List(Of Long)

For Each aUnit As baseclass.childclass In baseclass
    a.Add(baseclass.unitNumber)
Next

For Each bUnit As baseclassTwo.childclass In baseclassTwo
    b.Add(baseclassTwo.unitNumber)
Next

'I get End of statement expected here
Dim C As New List(Of Long) = a.except(b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Except()` returns an `IEnumerable(Of T)`, not a `List(Of T)`.
Also, make sure to `Import System.Linq` at the top:

```
Dim C As IEnumerable(Of Long) = a.Except(b)
```

or

```
Dim C As List(Of Long) = a.Except(b).ToList()
```

Remember: don't call `.ToList()` unless you really have to. Performance improves when you stick with `IEnumerable` for as long as possible.

```
Dim a As IEnumerable(Of Long) = baseclass.Select(Function(x) x.unitNumber)
Dim b As IEnumerable(Of Long) = baseclassTwo.Select(Function(x) x.unitNumber)
Dim c As IEnumerable(Of Long) = a.Except(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "New" keyword or separate your declaration from your assignment:

```
Dim C As List(Of Long) = a.except(b)
```

OR

```
Dim C As New List(Of Long)
C = a.except(b)
```

Comment: There's no good reason to include the `New` keyword in that second code snippet because doing so means that you are creating a new object on the first line that would be immediately discarded on the second line.  That ignores the fact that you're using incompatible types in that code such that it wouldn't compile anyway.